# How to connect MS Access database to Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I already put the access file in Desktop \data software\Data Software \bin\Debug, I want to connect to the database.

I try:

Tools-->connect to database-->Microsoft Access Database File -->browse the file.

The error:

`The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.`

Answer (score 0):

You need a driver for accessing the access file, in the correct version

so install

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255

You can deploy the driver in your projects.

Sometimes you need to test which version the file has, which the different download version